# Showing this a set of matrices is isomorphic to $A_4$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

Let $A$ be the set of these matrices and their permutations:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0& 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
So each has three permutations $P_1, P_{123}, P_{132}$ so in total there are 12 elements, so the order of $A$ is 12.

$A_4$ is the subgroup of even permutations in $S_4$. $A_4$ is also of order 12.

I get the intuition of how they are isomorphic, since $P_1, P_{123}, P_{132}$ are all even permutations, and both $A$ and $A_4$ are of order 12. So it would clearly be one to one and onto. I'm having trouble formally expressing how this represents an isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by "and their permutations"? are we permuting their rows, their columns, or both?

Comment: What do you mean by "and their permutations." Do you mean all possible multiples of these matrices?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 

Sorry, i've only learned to permute one way, so I hadn't thought about other ways. I permute the rows so for example for the matrix $$ \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$, we would have $$P_1 =  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, P_{123} =  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
Sorry, i've only learned to permute one way, so I hadn't thought about other ways. I permute the rows so for example for the matrix $$ \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$, we would have $$P_1 =  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, P_{123} =  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @J.Doe you repeated the same matrix twice.  Is that intentional? Is $P_1$ the identity permutation?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i edited my comment, hopefully it is more clear now.